# React: useLocation Hook doesn't exist in react-router-dom Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Hello I'm trying to import useLocation Hook from react-router-dom "typescript" I can't find it

as per React Router [Documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/hooks.md#uselocation) I'm pretty sure it exists.

Yet in typescript it keeps telling me there is not exported member called useLocation

This is how I import it:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
```

And this is the error I get:

> Module '"../../node_modules/@types/react-router-dom"' has no exported member 'useLocation'.ts(2305)

Comment: Try upgrading @types/react-router-dom to latest. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts#L35

Comment: Did you try ```import * as reactRouter from "react-router-dom"``` and then destructure the useLocation property?

Comment: Thank you guys, upgrading the package sovled my problem

Answer (score 2):

This is a typescript parsing error meaning the error is thrown by the package `@types/react-router-dom` and not the package `react-router-dom`, make sure you update and reinstall both.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to have both `react-router-dom` and `@types/react-router-dom` in version `5.x`

```
npm i react-router-dom@5
npm i -D @types/react-router-dom@5
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same challenge, running the following command resolved the problem

```
npm i --save-dev @types/react-router-dom
```